# How To Return URL's tagged with URL's

Tags: social-tag

I am looking for a way to return all the URL's and Site/Web Names for a given user who has tagged them with "I Like It".

I see a number of varieties throughout SharePoint but no out-of-the-box way that I can see which does this.

Before I go custom route I wanted to get some other ideas of how to accomplish this.

Thanks